# Define functions with foldl foldr

Tags: haskell, dictionary, functional-programming, fold

I understand the definitions of foldl, foldr, but I have problems with functions defined by them.

For example map with foldr:

```
map f []       = []
map f l   = foldr (\x xs -> f x : xs) [] l
```

I don't understand the `(\x xs -> f x : xs)`. It is the map function, which foldr takes? But shouldn't it be `(\x xs -> f x : f xs)`, because `map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs`?

Example with foldl:

```
concat (x:xs) = x ++ concat xs

concat' xs = foldl (++) [] xs
concat'' xs = foldl (\ys y -> ys ++ y) [] xs
```

Of course I understand `(++)`, but what's the logic behind `(\ys y -> ys ++ y)`? Is it `ys = []` and `y = xs`?
So the function takes `[]` as `ys` and `y` is the first element of `xs` and concates the `[]` with the `y`?
Concrete example:

```
concat'' [1,2,3] = foldl (\ys y -> ys ++ y) [] [1,2,3]
=> foldl (\ys y -> ys ++ y) ((\ys y -> ys ++ y) [] [1]) [2,3]
=> foldl (\ys y -> ys ++ y) [1] [2,3]
=> foldl (\ys y -> ys ++ y) ((\ys y -> ys ++ y) [1] [2]) [3]
=> foldl (\ys y -> ys ++ y) [1,2] [3]
=> foldl (\ys y -> ys ++ y) ((\ys y -> ys ++ y) [1,2] [3]) []
=> foldl (\ys y -> ys ++ y) [1,2,3] []
=> [1,2,3]
```

Another thing: `concat` only takes 1 list `xs`, so if I want to concat 2 lists?

```
concat (x:xs) ys = x ++ concat xs ys
concat [1,2,3] [4,5,6] with foldl?
```

Reverse:

```
reverse (x:xs) = reverse xs ++ [x]

reverse'  l = foldl (\xs x -> [x] : xs) [] l
reverse'' l = foldr (\x xs -> xs ++ [x]) [] l
```

The foldr is intuitive clear (with the questions from above), but what's behind the reverse order in foldl `(\xs x -> [x] : xs)`? This `foldl (\x xs -> xs ++ [x]) [] l` would be wrong, wouldn't it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: that's a couple of questions - for the first observe that the `xs` there already *was* mapped by `f` (look at the definition of `foldr` to see why) (also `f xs` would not be well-typed as you had `f :: a -> b` and at the same time `f :: [a] -> b'` so you would need to identify `a ~ [a]`)

Comment: Note that `foldr f z [x1, x2, x3] = f x1 (f x2 (f x3 z))` so the `xs` was already mapped by `f`.

Comment: for the second: just note that `foldl` will *loop* through `xs` from the left (again look at the definition)

Comment: for the very last: it's just the difference between folding from left vs folding from right - just try your different implementation and have a look for yourself!

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
foldr (\x xs -> ...) end list
```

could be read, roughly, as follows

- scan the whole `list`
- if it's empty, just return end `end`
- otherwise:

  - let `x` be the element at hand
  - let `xs` be the rest of the list, *after having been processed*
  - apply the `...` operation

The emphasized part is crucial. `xs` is *not* the rest of the list, but the result of the "recursive call" on it.

Indeed, `xs` is a bad name for that. In thee general case, it's not even a list! E.g. one would never write (silly example)

```
foldr (\x xs -> x + xs) 0 [1..100]  -- sum 1..100
```

but rather prefer something like

```
foldr (\x partialSum -> x + partialSum) 0 [1..100]  -- sum 1..100
```

(Actually, one would not sum using `foldr`, but let's leave that aside.)

So, just read it like this:

```
map f l   = foldr (\x mappedTail -> f x : mappedTail) [] l
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand foldr.
map with foldl would be like this? `map f l   = foldl (\x xs -> x : f xs) [] l`
So `x` is the mapped part and `xs` is mapped on?

Comment: @user22709 Morally yes, but note that in that case `x` is a (mapped) list, and `xs` is an element so it should be `foldl (\x xs -> x ++ [f xs]) [] list`

Comment: Thank you!
Do you have a suggestion for a more elegant way to write that, because xs is normally the rest of the list, which isn't the case here...

Comment: @user22709 Actually, I would avoid foldl since appending at the end as in `.. ++ [..]` is known to be inefficient. If you still want, simply choose some reasonable names for `x,xs`.